# Error when tryhing to rebuild an RPM

Tags: rpm

I just use Linux for a LAMP server. I'm currently installing Apache 2.4 on CentOS 6.4 (x64).

How do I resolve this error below?

```
rpmbuild: arguments to --root (-r) must begin with a /
[root@microtrack src]# rpmbuild --rebuild /distcache-1.4.5-23.src.rpm
error: cannot open /distcache-1.4.5-23.src.rpm: No such file or directory
```

Comment: change `rpmbuild -rebuild` to `rpmbuild --rebuild` and try.

Comment: FYI: The error shows *below* the command. So your picture doesn't show the command that gave the "arguments to --root" error.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text; post the *text itself*...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`rebuild` needs two dashes, not one. `--rebuild`.

Comment: Christ it even has that on the guide I'm follwing :/ - Thanks man!

Comment: I'm confused. The question says that already.